# Xcode5 ios7, how do I update my app from iPhone 5s only to universal?

Tags: ios7, xcode5, ios-universal-app

My app was just accepted to the app store and works fine, but I noticed that on iPhone 4s and lower (smaller screen size) the app doesn't show full screen. The same with my app on the iPad. How would I switch to a universal app? Thanks!

Comment: Anyone? New to coding and everything.

Answer (score 0):

I think for the iPad you would have to recreate the app and select univarsal instead of iPhone. The copy and paste the code fram the old one to the new file.

For the iPhone 4s in the viewDidload you will have to enter this

```
    if ([[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds].size.height == 568) {
        //code for iPhone 5 which you have already done

    } else {
        //code for iPhone 4s like resizing images
```

}